# Discord.js How can I check if a mention user in my command has a role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create an `if` statement that detects if the message author has a role named `System Control Authority - 50`. If so, they cannot use the command. How can I do it?

```js
const sys10 = client.guilds.cache
 .get('745816516238245888')
 .roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'System Control Authority - 10');

if (cmd == 'aerial') {
 message.delete({ timeout: 10 });
 if (!sys10 && !devRole && !adminRole && !qgRole && !qgtsRole) {
  return func.Loi(
   'You cannot use this command.\nRequire role: **System Control Authority - 10**'
  );
 }
 const takelinda = message.mentions.members.first().id;
 if (takelinda == '669723732708687882') {
  return func.Loi(message, 'You cannot use this command to me =)))');
 }
 return message.channel.send(
  '*<@' +
   message.author.id +
   '>:*\nSystem Call.\nGenerate Aerial Element.\nBurst Element!\n*<@' +
   takelinda +
   '>: ahhhhh*\n*System: <@' +
   takelinda +
   '> has been defeated.*'
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Collection#some`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method.

```js
// get the member's roles, check if any of them pass the name test
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'System Control Authority - 10')
  return func.Loi(message, 'You have the System Control Authority - 10 role, so you cannot use this command')
```

---

For more information, visit [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-check-if-a-guild-member-has-a-certain-role) and [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions) page from the official `discord.js` guide